Identify a movie about scientist with synthesized brain to computer
I am looking for movie but I know only the first few minutes of it. So I will try to describe them with as much detail as possible.
So movie starts with probably a scientist walking through town where there are some children playing with their phones but their are not working because there is no signal service and internet. Then he arrives to a garden of his dead co-workers and starts telling a story about what happened. As one of his co-workers was dying and his wife decided to synthesize his brain to computer a and then he escaped to internet...
Does anyone recognize this movie?

Sounds like the movie Transcendence starring Johnny Depp:

A scientist's drive for artificial intelligence, takes on dangerous
  implications when his consciousness is uploaded into one such program.

Source
